# Why is my array test code not printing?

Tags: php, arrays

This PHP Code is not working for some reason. It's meant to output this
"

```
hey aa
hey ab
hey ac
hey ad
hey ae
hey af
hey ag
```

..." and so on
But it isn't printing anything.
My code is
(not showing properly, so here's a 0bin link, feel free to edit this to add the code http://0bin.net/paste/KOoJCjVYk5xhVLAl#0yMutTpnTtm7+JBex6bxqJ0XGM716kB8X91QNXGgHAD)

```
<p>test</p>
<?
$array = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "!", "'", "·", "$", "%", "&", "/", "(", ")", "=", " ");
$array2 = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "!", "'", "·", "$", "%", "&", "/", "(", ")", "=", " ");
$integer = 0;
$integer2 = 0;
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $integer = $integer + 1;
 foreach ($array2 as $value) {

     ?><p><?echo ("hey " . $array[$integer][0] . $array2[$integer2][0]); ?></p><?
    $integer2 = $integer2 + 1;
}   
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've several errors on your code, try the following:

```
$array = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "!", "'", "·", "\$", "%", "&", "/", "(", ")", "=", " ");
$array2 = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "!", "'", "·", "\$", "%", "&", "/", "(", ")", "=", " ");

foreach ($array as $value) {
 foreach ($array2 as $value2) {
    echo "<p>{$value}{$value2}</p>";
  }   
}
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/IbuFve)

---

Explanation:

1. `$integer = $integer + 1;` is the same as `$integer++`, but, in this
   case, you don't need it.
2. You're using the the same variable (`$value`) for both loops.
3. `$array[$integer][0]` doesn't make any sense in your loop, because the value you need is in...`$value`.
4. `PHP` comes with a manual and [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) is there ;)

Comment: "{$value}{$value2}

"; } } ?>" that's what it outputs.

Comment: Please check the ideone demo